# How to prevent Client DOM XSS vulnerability in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After checkmarx scan on my code,I am getting the below message.

> Method execute at line 23 of ...\action\searchFun.js  gets user input for the form element.
>
> This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in function at line 28 of ../action/searchFun.js. This may enable a DOM XSS attack.

Could some help me how to sanitize the above scenario to satisfy Checkmarx?
Script as follows:

```
function searchAnnouncements(){
  $('#loadingAnnouncements').html('Loading...');
  var formData = $('form').serialize();

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:  "bat.ajax",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(json) {
      $('div.block').unblock();
      $('#loadingAnnouncements').html('');
      if (json.resultSize > 0)
        $('#searchResults').html(json.searchResult);
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: So is it complaining about html line?? Good luck... If you are returning html from the server and displaying it, it could be an issue. Only way to avoid it is not send HTML and parse a JSON and build the DOM. Or you could find some XSS remover script, but that can miss things. Or you can just ignore the warning and enjoy your coffeee.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DOMPurify` library.
https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

This should prevent XSS injection by keeping safe HTML tags.

```
function searchAnnouncements(){
  $('#loadingAnnouncements').html('Loading...');
  var formData = $('form').serialize();

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:  "bat.ajax",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(json) {
      $('div.block').unblock();
      $('#loadingAnnouncements').html('');
      if (json.resultSize > 0)
        $('#searchResults').html(DOMPurify.sanitize(json.searchResult));
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude $().text method doesn't render the DOM. I think in this case he wants to render the response content to the DOM rather than showing as a plain text.

Comment: You're right, I replyed a bit too fast. I didn't think he actually retrieved HTML from the server. I just cancelled my downvote.

Comment: If I add DOMPurify.sanitize(), do i need to add any dependency/js file?
Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Tejeswani Yes, as mentioned in the answer, you have to add dompurify.js file.  All the installing steps are defined in the provided URL.

Comment: To use DOMPurify.sanitize, do we need to add any library/dependency? Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Tejeswani Yes. You need to add the dompurify js file. read more about here how you can install it. https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#using-the-minified-and-tested-production-version-source-map-available

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to be similar to the following:

```
function searchAnnouncements(){  
    $("#loadingAnnouncements").html("Loading...");
    var formData = $("#form").serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url:  "bat.ajax",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
            $("#div.block").unblock();
            $("#loadingAnnouncements").html('');
            if (json.resultSize > 0)
              $("#searchResults").html(DOMPurify.sanitize(json.searchResult));
        });   
    }, 
}
```

Comment: Please spend a little time on learning how to format code properly on SO. See my changes to your question.